# Controlling what appear with ui router nested states and views

Tags: angularjs, templates, angular-ui-router

Is it possible to control what appears on nested states with ui-router using multiple named views.

For example if I use the parent state to name my shell page, I then should be able to use the nested state to control what divs/sections appear on the home state and nested state... right?

For example

```
.state('home')
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'views/search.client.view.html'
})
.state('home.search', {
  url: 'search',
  views: {
    'logo@': {
      templateUrl: 'views/search.logo.client.view.html'
     },
    'user@': {
      templateUrl: 'views/header.authentication.client.view.html'
     },
    'jumbotron@home': {
    templateUrl: 'views/search.jumbotron.client.view.html'
       }
     'resultsui@home.search': {
     templateUrl: 'views/search.client.view.resultsui.html'
          }
        }
      })
```

So I want the logo and the user views to display on both states, `'home'` and `'home.search'`. However I only want the jumbotron to display on the home state and I want the resultui to display on the home.search state. Their divs should replace the other one's on their respective states - isn't that how this is suppose to work?

And then in my shell page `'views/search.client.view.html'` I simply put `<div ui-view""></div>` and `<div ui-view="logo@"></div>` etc in the locations I want them?

**UPDATE**
I think I have a little better understanding of how to accomplish this, I will update with an answer if it works.

Comment: `ui-view="logo@"` should be `ui-view="logo"`

Comment: @PankajParkar - to get the logo to display on both states?

Comment: for that you had already mentioned `'logo@'`(relative named views) in `views` object